# Programmatically get list of MVC Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Is there a way to get a list of all the Views defined in an ASP.NET MVC project?  Is there a built-in enumeration anywhere or should I be looking toward reflection?

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically accessible View Names is one of the many features offered by the [T4MVC template](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/07/28/t4mvc-2-4-updates-settings-file-sub-view-folders-actionname-support-and-more.aspx). If it should not fit your needs exactly, you can still have a look and see how it's done there.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is your friend in this case. I don't think the enumeration exists already.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines should get you started

```
for (methods in controller)    
    typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.ReturnType)
```

that's pseudo, not sure if it's the proper properties and what not... the one thing you'll have to be careful of is only get methods on the declaringtype, not on the base types.

```
typeof(Controller).GetMethods(
    BindingFlags.Instance | 
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
    BindingFlags.Public)
```

hope that's enough to be dangerous and get you started.

Comment: As best I can tell, this will only get the action methods that are part of the controller - not the views associated with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP.NET MVC favors convention over configuration, your best bet is to look at all the files under the ~/Views directory -- no reflection needed.